# how to get all div tags class attributes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, attributes

I want to display all class name attributes which is inside a div. For Example :

```html
<div class="limit-text">
  <h1 class="h1 title-cover">Title</h1>
  <img src="image.jpg" class="icon-svg hide-for-print" alt="image">
  <h3 class="copy-cover">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
</div>
```

The output should be as : `limit-text, h1 title-cover, icon-svg hide-for-print, copy-cover` . Getting all Class name attributes. I Tried

```
$(div).attr('class')
```

but its returning only one (i.e) limit-text

Please help me on this.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/find/. It took me 10secs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve class names of all child elements at multiple level in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334063/how-to-retrieve-class-names-of-all-child-elements-at-multiple-level-in-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024631/finding-all-class-names-used-in-html-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `children()` and loop through each of them to get classnames

```js
$('.limit-text').children().andSelf().each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('class'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="limit-text">
  <h1 class="h1 title-cover">Title</h1>
  <img src="image.jpg" class="icon-svg hide-for-print" alt="image">
  <h3 class="copy-cover">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Change to `.children().addBack()` (for jquery>1.8 - for jquery<3.0  can also use `.andSelf()`) if you want to include the top level div, as in OPs example output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

Create an empty array to save classes.
Then iterate on all tags inside the body which are not script tags.

Get classes one by one a push them into the array created a the first line.

Then log the classes.

```js
var classes = [];

$('body *:not(script)').each(function(){
  _classes = $(this).attr('class') ? $(this).attr('class').split(' ') : []
  _classes.forEach(function(entry){
    if(classes.indexOf(entry) < 0){
      classes.push(entry)
    }
  })
})

console.log(classes)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="limit-text">
  <h1 class="h1 title-cover">Title</h1>
  <img src="image.jpg" class="icon-svg hide-for-print" alt="image">
  <h3 class="copy-cover">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: ... and what does it do? Mind adding some explaination to your code.

Comment: It creates an empty array to save classes.
Then we iterate on all tags inside the body which are not script tags.
We get classes one by one a push them into the array we created a the first line.
Then we log the classes.

Comment: Update your answer with the description; don't add that in comments.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
$(div).attr('class')
```

you can get the class name of the parent div - this one you have already.

Using:

```
$(div).find('[class]').toArray().map(child => $(child).attr('class'))
```

or

```
$(div).find('[class]').toArray().map(child => child.className)
```

you can get an array of all children classes.

```
["h1 title-cover", "icon-svg hide-for-print", "copy-cover"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div= document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute("class");
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].getAttribute("class");
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
[0].getAttribute("class");
var h3 = document.getElementsByTagName('h3')
[0].getAttribute("class");
var result = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${div}, ${h1}, ${img} ,${h3}`;
//or
console.log(result)
```

```html
<div class="limit-text">
  <h1 class="h1 title-cover">Title</h1>
  <img src="image.jpg" class="icon-svg hide-for-print" alt="image">
  <h3 class="copy-cover">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
</div>

<p id='result'></p>
```